# Add more horizontal space in an array

Tags: spacing, arrays

Is there a setting I can input to the `array` environment, which will slightly increase the horizontal spacing between each entry?

I would appreciate it if you could test your code on the following example I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr} 
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{% repeat text
   \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2} } 
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{*{5}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \ldots \\
\rpt[4]{\downarrow &} \unskip \downarrow \\
x_{1}^1 & x_{1}^2 & x_{2}^1 & x_{1}^3 & \ldots \\
\end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

I want slightly more whitespace between each number, between each arrow, and between each x.

[image: table.png]

Comment: See [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764) for general spacing adaptations (it holds for `tabular` and `array`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add something like

```
\setlength\arraycolsep{20pt}
```

before the array.